# What might cause a .resx file to compile correctly under Windows XP, but fail with error 137 under Windows 7 64 bit?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-7, 64-bit

I have run into a very strange scenario. There is a .resx file in my solution causing problems.

Using Visual Studio 2010 running under Windows XP, the solution compiles without problems.

Using Visual Studio 2010 running under Windows 7, 64 bit, the same solution reports a build failure with error 137

`An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. Line 204, position 5.  [Path Sanitized]\RemoteFileView.resx`

The resource file in question appears to be valid, so I am at a loss to explain the problem.

Can anyone suggest what might have gone wrong?

Clarification: The line in question that VS 2010 is complaining about is a simple </data> element. The XML appears to be well formed.

Comment: Just to add to the fun, I can comment out the elements for which the error is generated, and the application builds. Of course, because it's missing resources it looks ugly... but it does run!

Comment: try to compile all as 32-bit or 64-bit, sounds like mismatch of project compilations

Comment: @Richard What are the elements for which the error is generated? Icons by any chance?

Comment: Are you running Visual Studio as Administrator?

Comment: @kzen The elements in question are indeed icons, but encapsulated within an ImageList.

Comment: @Ryk Typically Visual Studio is not being run as an Administrator. I did try running as Administrator with the same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the string in the error message, there is a [BadImageFormatException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.badimageformatexception.aspx) being thrown when the designer is trying to load.

It seems highly likely that it's a bitness mismatch issue. Have you tried rebuilding the solution? Can you build on the command line via MSBuild? Are all of your projects targetting "Any CPU", or do you have a processor specific project?

Please take a look at [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/06/19/resgen-exe-error-an-attempt-was-made-to-load-a-program-with-an-incorrect-format.aspx) where Sara Joiner describes the circumstances where you may see this issue in detail.

Comment: The project in question is targeting a 32-bit build. (Sadly one of the components is 32-bit only, forcing that requirement). The project builds correctly using MSBuild from the command line.

Comment: Can you take a look at the link I added to the answer? I think this is the same issue you're hitting.

Comment: The blog post you referenced was a great help. Not only does it describe the problem in a much clearer way than my initial question, it also provides many ways to resolve it. Thank you for the pointer.

Comment: Ooerr! It seems you didn't get the full bounty you deserved. I've posted the problem on meta (at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79422). Hopefully you'll get the rest of it soon.

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same issue when migrating my system to 64-bit. The only solution for me was that every time I changed something in the gui and the resx-files updated, I had to do the following:

Replace all occurences of the string `j00L` to `j0yL`.

You will now be able to compile!

Comment: Wow, this actually worked for me. How did you ever figure this out?!?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug with Visual Studio that microsoft has known about for over a year. See below links for more information:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/06/19/resgen-exe-error-an-attempt-was-made-to-load-a-program-with-an-incorrect-format.aspx#comments
- https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/532584/error-when-compiling-resx-file-seems-related-to-beta2-bug-5252020?wa=wsignin1.0
- https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/554759/error-in-control-resx-file-when-adding-imagelist
- https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/586646/the-generateresource-task-failed-unexpectedly

I recently had to upgrade our windows forms project to .NET 4.0 because as soon as we touched (read saved) a designer it correupted our embedded images. The line of the error was just a load of bollocks.

Unfortunately none of the suggested workarounds worked for us so we had to bite the bullet and upgrade.